# Make flexbox children fill 100% height when another child has a bigger font size

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I have my problem below.

```css
.app-main-header {
  background-color: blue;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.app-main-header > div:first-child {
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.app-main-header > div {
  background-color: red;
  height: 200%;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.app-main-header > div + div {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  border-left: 1px solid grey;
}

.app-hamburger {
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="app-main-header">
  <div>
    About
  </div>
  <div>
    Contact
  </div>
  <div class="app-hamburger">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `About` and `Contact` boxes are smaller in comparison to the hamburger icon as its `font-size` is bigger. Is there anyway to make `About` and `Contact` box size match the hamburger without increasing `font-size`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get rid of `align-items: center` on `.app-main-header`, and you get rid of `height: 200%` on `.app-main-header > div`, your nav items will all take the full height of the nav bar.

The only problem that presents is that the text isn't quite vertically centered that way. So to fix that, you can add a span inside those divs, and use `display: flex` on the divs with `display: block; margin: auto` on the spans.

```css
.app-main-header {
  background-color: blue;
  /*align-items: center;*/
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;

}
.app-main-header > div:first-child {
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.app-main-header > div{
  background-color :red;
  /*height: 200%;*/
  padding: 10px 0;
  display: flex;
}
.app-main-header > div span {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
.app-main-header > div + div {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  border-left: 1px solid grey;
}
.app-hamburger {
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="app-main-header">
    <div>
        <span>About</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>Contact</span>
    </div>
    <div class="app-hamburger">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned you should remove `align-items: center` and `height: 200%` to allow flex-items stretch.

But no need for extra spans here. You can make you flex items become a nested flex containers (as done in [cjl750's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45497901/1548895)) and add `align-items: center`. This will work because text nodes are considered as anonymous flex items.

From [flexbox specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-items):

> Each in-flow child of a [flex container](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-container) becomes a [flex item](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-item), and each contiguous run of text that is directly contained inside a [flex container](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-container) is wrapped in an anonymous [flex item](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-item). However, an anonymous flex item that contains only [white space](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#white-space-prop) (i.e. characters that can be affected by the [`white-space`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/#white-space) property) is not rendered (just as if it were `display:none`).

Demo:

```css
.app-main-header {
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.app-main-header > div:first-child {
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.app-main-header > div {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.app-main-header > div + div {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  border-left: 1px solid grey;
}

.app-hamburger {
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="app-main-header">
  <div>
    About
  </div>
  <div>
    Contact
  </div>
  <div class="app-hamburger">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```